# Create slideshow with date as caption automatically

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, metadata, slideshow

I want to create a slide show of photos and want the create-date of each image to appear at the bottom when the image is being shown in the slide show.

Is there a way I can automate this using software like ffmpeg or and other(do suggest).

PS. I do not want to do it manually as there are a lot of images and it will take for ever to do so, hence asking for an automatic way.

Thanks

Comment: You could have a look into imagemagick. It is able to create an overlay text on an image. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236898/add-text-on-image-at-specific-point-using-imagemagick)

Comment: It might help if you add the operating system you are using

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: What format do you want to use to save the slidshow ? mp4, gif, webp, avi....

Comment: Have you given up on this?

Comment: No, I haven't. I am using irfanview, which lets me batch edit photos and place exif data as text on the image. But still have not found a way to create a slide show in ffmpeg that takes different orientations and resolution images.